# How to mapping nested json object to model in angular 11?

Tags: angular, typescript, observable, httpclient

I want to fill my Person class in angular with nested objects
my api response is :

```
{
"id": "1001614505887752423",
"type": 1,
"name": "test contact",
"createdAt": "1399/12/10 - 09:51",
"updatedAt": "1399/12/10 - 09:51",
"addresses": [
  {
    "id": "1001614505887757358",
    "personId": "1001614505887752423",
    "companyId": null,
    "cityId": 66,
    "address": "test",
    "postalCode": "485484",
    "updatedAt": "1399/12/10 - 09:51",
    "createdAt": "1399/12/10 - 09:51"
  },
  {
    "id": "100161450588776282",
    "personId": "1001614505887752423",
    "companyId": null,
    "cityId": 45,
    "address": "test",
    "postalCode": "48548",
    "updatedAt": "1399/12/10 - 09:51",
    "createdAt": "1399/12/10 - 09:51"
  }
]
```

}

And my Person Class with a array of object as property:

```
 export class Person {
   id: string;
   name: string;
   type: number;
   addresses: Array<Address>;

   createdAt: string;
   updatedAt: string;
  }


export class Address{
id: string;
address: string;
postalCode: string;
cityId: number;
createdAt: string;
updatedAt: string;
}
```

All prop's filled but Address[] not fill ,
I call httpclient like this:

```
   this.http.get<Person>(url).subscribe(x => this.model = x);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll suggest two solutions

1- If you are not going to create class methods, you could just use an interface. So your code become like that:

```
export interface Person {
    id: string;
    name: string;
    type: number;
    addresses: Address[];
    createdAt: string;
    updatedAt: string;
}

export interface Address {
    id: string;
    address: string;
    postalCode: string;
    cityId: number;
    createdAt: string;
    updatedAt: string;
}
```

---

2- If you really need to use clasess so you need to initialize your class as what you're doing right now is not. New code:

```
export class Person {
    id: string;
    name: string;
    type: number;
    addresses: Address[];
    createdAt: string;
    updatedAt: string;

    constructor(personObject: any) {
        this.id = personObject.id;
        this.name = personObject.name;
        this.type = personObject.type;
        this.createdAt = personObject.createdAt;
        this.updatedAt = personObject.updatedAt;
        this.addresses = personObject.addresses.map((a: any) => new Address(a));
    }
}

export class Address {
    id: string;
    address: string;
    postalCode: string;
    cityId: number;
    createdAt: string;
    updatedAt: string;

    constructor(addressObject: any) {
        this.id = addressObject.id;
        this.address = addressObject.address;
        this.postalCode = addressObject.postalCode;
        this.cityId = addressObject.cityId;
        this.createdAt = addressObject.createdAt;
        this.updatedAt = addressObject.updatedAt;
    }
}
```

Then your api request:

```
 this.http.get<Person>(url).subscribe(x => this.model = new Person(x));
```

Comment: tanks a lot you solve my problem but I have a new problem with FormGroup with the constructor in this line: this.formGroup = this.fb.formGroup<Person>(Person, this.model);

Comment: thanks use  constructor param with questions mark and solved form builder error